# iPhone Stock/Ticker Search

Tags: iphone, search, stocks

I'm trying to build a financial iPhone app that has a stock search as one of its features. I noticed that the Bloomberg app (and the default Stock app) query online whenever they're looking for stocks.  Does anyone know how they do this?  I once built a PHP backend that queried the Yahoo Finance API using http requests but I doubt this is what they do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Yahoo Finance Web Service to get quotes, maybe it's not the way that Bloomberg does it, but it works.  You can request this information using `NSURLRequest` but the data comes back in comma separated values, so you will need to parse out the quotes.  There's probably a method or two in `NSString` to deal with this format.

Off the top of my head I don't know of any other web services out there that provide stock info, I'm sure there are, but you said you worked with Yahoo Finance and PHP backend so it seems like nothing you can't handle.

Comment: My gosh, I didn't think fetching would be the option but I might as well get cracking lol.  Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine the system Bloomberg uses is proprietary and not open to web service calls and so on.

Like what Convolution has said I'd imagine there is a platform out there you can use to query for stock data

Perhaps this blog post will help?

http://benjisimon.blogspot.com/2009/01/truly-simple-stock-api.html

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I worked on the Yahoo API in PHP and in Java so I'm pretty familiar with that one.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The Mergent Company Fundamentals API is great for looking up companies based on the ticker symbol (and can do much more): http://www.mergent.com/servius/